# Trying to make many polygons from points?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, point

I am trying to turns points into polygons, but I encounter this challenge :

My data set has 1000 entries. Each entry has 360 associated columns, each with a coordinate pair. When connected, these coordinate pairs should all draw a specific circle or circle-like shape. So, the end result I am looking for is 1000 polygons, one for each entry.

It's a fairly large set to work with, so I am trying to strategize the best approach. What would you do?

It doesn't seem feasible to use Display XY Data --> Point to Line --> Line to Point for each entry. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you're looking for an arcpy solution, as your tags indicate, then please show us what you have tried so far and how it failed to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I am a beginner with arcpy and python, so no code to show. But I included the tag in case that was the direction I needed to pursue and someone wanted to give some pointers involving a script or something like that.

Comment: Are you saying you have 1000 records where each record includes 720 columns of X or Y coordinates that form a circle like shape?  Or are there 360 columns?  Or are there separate files?  Your description of how your data is laid out is very vague.  Ideally all coordinate pairs would be transposed from a single record into two columns of coordinate in the same order, all sharing the same ID of the original record in a column (i.e., 360,000 records with 1000 ID sets).  Then the 3 steps you mentioned would create all 1000 lines all in one go.

Comment: A polygon is an **ordered** list of vertices. You need to preserve order OR use a convex hull function on a pointcluster.  Don't forget to close the poly with the starting vertex.  Policy here at GIS SE is for coding questions is to start with a good-faith effort at code; this allows our volunteers to help you without having to become a coding service.

Comment: As the data is now, each record has 360 columns of an X,Y pair.
I was thinking the same thing as Richard, and I gave it a try on a small subset. I ran into a few issues (separate questions perhaps), mainly that (1) getting the data in this order is tedious and (2) the point to line function connects all the circles to each other, thus messing up some of the polygons down the line

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification.  The [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) gives details of how things work here.

Comment: Thanks Vince... I made a large list of 3 columns: ID, X, and Y. I closed the polygon by adding the starting point to the end of the list. Then, however, that ending point is connected to the next polygon's starting point.. Any advice?

Comment: You need to *provide code* before we can help you.  The formal name is a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did this manually, no code (in response to a suggestion above). I arranged data in excel into three columns (ID, X, Y). Then tweaked it so the start and end points for each ID are the same. Then I did Display XY --> Point to Line --> Feature to Polygon, as suggested above. I understand what you are saying about providing code... but my question is about the process and which method to pursue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert each table record into 360 points

Calculate minimum spanning tree.

Dissolve 359 lines into one

Convert line vertices.  to polygon

Proceed with next record

Yes it is script

Update

@Vince idea will work better, points to multipoint and convex hull of it. Convex hull is built-in method for arcpy geomety